# The DOM showing elements from previous screen [Appium]

Tags: react-native, automation, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

While inspecting the Android Application using Appium-Inspector, some elements from previous screen are also getting inspected and are present in the Element Hierarchy.

The App is built on react-native.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ignoreUnimportantViews=true capability to get only active screen elements. Keep in mind that this capability is only applicable for Android See more at https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

Answer (score 0):

Try refresh screen by clicking the refresh button in the inspector, that usually solves it for me in react-native app

[image: appium refresh]